# Images won't display in Wordpress template

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

At the moment i got an issue where i have images in my asset folder but when i am converting my HTML/CSS/JS template to wordpress some images won't display and some do. The biggest issue i have is that i have to display the image where you land on the website. This is the CSS code:

```
#hero {
background: url('wp-content/themes/brandingyou/assets/img/iceland.jpg') center center / cover no-repeat;
padding: 40px 0;
color: white;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
<section id="hero" class="demo">
    <h1><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
    <div class="container">
       <h2><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></h2> 
    </div>
    <a href="#making-brand"><span></span>Scroll</a>
</section><!-- Hero -->
```

And this is the current result:

[image: How it now looks]

And it should look like this:
[image: How it should look]

There are several more images that have the same problem. Anyone has a clue why it does this?

NOTE: Not all images have this issue
Note 2: I have tried different file formats, didn't help

Comment: If the parent element of `#hero` does not have a defined height, then setting `height: 100%` on a child will resolve to `height: 0`. This seems to be what's happening in your first image. If you set the height of `#hero` to something static, like `height: 500px;`,  does the image start to appear? If so, consider something like  `height: calc(100vh - 50px)`, but replace `50px` with the height of the gray bar at the top of your page.

Comment: Cheers! This seems to stretch it out to the full height!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are including the img via CSS, so height 100%, won´t work, use better 100vh (viewport height), and get sure you are indicating the correct source for the image, if you are working in a theme yo don´t have to search the img in wht folder wp content, just use a relative path like ../img/your-image.jpg or something like that

Comment: Thank you for your response. i tried many different options to get a solution to the image problem. Eventually i just copied working code and changed the image name and the end of the code. That did the trick. After that i was still annoyed so i kept looking and noticed i missed a ' / ' .....